# To add a tab to Oracle form

Tags: oracle, tabs, oracleforms

I am given a form to modify, i need to add a tab to the form. I never did this can you please give me some material or an example form of how to add a tab, to kick-start the things.

Thanks ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form already has tabs then it is easy:

1. In the object navigator, expand the Canvases node
2. Expand the node for the canvas that has the tabs
3. Expand the tab pages node
4. Add a new tab page (click green + button)
5. Specify the attributes of the new tab page, e.g. label

[image]

Comment: Hi Tony.. that was helpful, do you have any link where i can read about placing a tab, getting there values, using triggers on them..etc

Comment: A good place to start is the Oracle Forms Documention accessible from Oracle Form Builder --> help --> on line help. Search for the following: "Creating a Tab Canvas". This walks you through creating a tab canvas and under heading "related topics" are further links on working with the Tab Canvas